# Get handles of all edges or all patches in a figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, handle, mesh

When using functions such as `trimesh` in Matlab, lots of `'line'` objects are drawn (that are the edges of the mesh). Now I need to change a property on all of them.

How can I get a list of handles to all the `'line'` objects that belong to a particular plot (i.e. a set of axes)? Same for `'patch'` objects.

Comment: if you want to change all lines, why don't you set the correct property from the beginning, when you plot the mesh?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33713-bar-setfacealpha/content/bar_setFaceAlpha.m) for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in this [post](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/248850):

To get all `'line'` objects on the current set of axes:

```
lines = findobj(gca, 'type', 'line');
```

For patches, it's similar.

What was also helpful was displaying the types of objects under the current axes. For example:

```
>> mesh(magic(5))
>> get(findobj(gca), 'type')

ans = 

    'axes'
    'surface'
```

If there are many lines, such as after `trimesh`, and we just want to know what different types of objects there are in an axes object:

```
>> unique(get(findobj(gca), 'type'))

ans = 

    'axes'
    'line'
```

is more useful than

```
>> get(findobj(gca), 'type')

ans = 

    'axes'
    'line'
    'line'
    'line'
    'line'
    'line'
    ...
```

Here's an example of how to set a property on all of them:

```
set(findobj(gca, 'type', 'surface'), 'FaceColor', 'interp')
```